# Click Class Goal Conversion Does Not Work Properly [Google Tag Manager]

Tags: events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, form-submit

I have set up a click class event goal on Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics but it does not work properly.

It works on Google Tag Manager preview and also shows as working when using `Google Analytics > Real Time > Events`.

However, it does not display as a completed goal in `Google Analytics > Acquisitions > Channels`.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a fix or is it just an error with these Google Products?

I seem to have this issue with many goals where it works in preview and displays as triggering in real time but then does not transfer to `Acquisitions > channels`.

Comment: You do not expect to see events both in real time report and in any of the aggregated reports.. Give GA TWO days to populate the aggregated reports. Or four hours if you're paying for GA. If you don't know whether you're paying for it or no, - you're not paying

Comment: Did you set a goals in GA?